# Asp.net mvc: My event listeners (in the View <script> tag) only work once

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have seen this question on stackOverflow, but it didn't help me, because my code is entirely different.
I am trying to make a menu appear when right-clicking an image, and it works fine, but only once.
Here is my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div class="container div1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 2)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position:relative; background-image: url(@Model[i].ImgLink); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" />
                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count; i += 2)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid" />

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="out-click"></div>
</div>





<div class="container div2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position:relative; background-image: url(@Model[i].ImgLink); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" />
                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid" />

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 2; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid" />

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="out-click"></div>
</div>
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .play-btn {
        width: 3.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
        opacity: 0;

        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .img-fluid{
        width: 30em;
        height: auto;
    }
    .hov:hover .play-btn{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .row .column {
        flex: 33.3%;
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 4px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .row .column .img-fluid {
         margin-top: 2%;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
    }

    .menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px lightgrey;
        position: absolute;
        transform-origin: center;
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    }

        .menu.show {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
            transform-origin: top left;
        }

    .menu-item {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        transition: 0.1s;
        color: #666;
    }

        .menu-item:hover {
            background-color: #eee;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .out-click {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
    }

    @@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        .row .column {
            flex: 50%;
        }
        .play-btn {
            width: 3em;
        }
        .img-fluid{
            
        }
    }

    @@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .row .column {
            flex: 100%;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
</style>

@section scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width <= 800 && width > 600) {
            $(".div2").remove();
        }
        else {
            $(".div1").remove();
        }
        const clickable = $(".clickable");
        const menu = $(".menu");
        const outClick = $(".out-click");

        for (var i = 0; i < clickable.length; i++) {
            clickable[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                    menu[j].style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
                    menu[j].style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
                    menu[j].classList.add('show');
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) {
                    outClick[j].style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < outClick.length; i++) {
            outClick[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                    menu[j].classList.remove('show');
                }
                outClick[i].style.display = "none";
            });
        }
        
    });
    
</script>
}
```

I only did it for the first image in div1 and div2 classes, for a test. I copied part of the code for the event listeners from here:
https://technokami.in/custom-right-click-context-menu-using-html-css-javascript
If my View is too big for you to find what is wrong with it, visit the above page because it contains just the event listeners with the problem. Also, because I have more than one image I want to react to the right-click, I used classes instead of id-s to get the elements. And inside the  tag I have to use for-s, because the classes return a collection of elements. That should be the only difference. I also tried putting the code outside the document.ready and it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't really understand js well or jQuery, I corrected it. For some reason it couldn't find the elements of the class "out-click", and I was getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLDivElement." error. I put the last instruction from my script in another for; `for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) { outClick[j].style.display = "none";}` and it worked.